# jQuery not getting changed input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

Ive got a button with id 'filter' and also two input fields:

```
<input type="text" name="Status" value="{{ $Status }}">
<input type="text" name="CusJobNum" value="{{ $CusJobNum }}">
```

Then I have this jQuery script

```
$(document).on('click', '#filter', function(){
    var url = 'JobsByDate/?';
    $('input').each(function(){
        var a = $(this).attr('name');
        var b = $(this).attr('value');
        if(!(b == ''))
            url = url + '&'+a+'='+b;
    });

    window.location = url;
});
```

The code is only getting the default value for the input even if i make a change to the field. Does anyone know why?

Comment: use `var b = $(this).val();`

Answer (score 3):

Use [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to get the value, as of now you are reading its attribute. the method [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) is used to get attribute value

```
var b = $(this).val();
```

*OR*, Go native

```
var b = this.value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using **[`attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)** method to get the value which always return the attribute value in the markup. You should use **[`val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val/)** method to get the current value of the element.

```
var b = $(this).val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `val()` to get value of input.

```
 $(document).on('click', '#filter', function(){
        var url = 'JobsByDate/?';
        $('input').each(function(){
            var a = $(this).attr('name');
            var b = $(this).val();
            if(!(b == ''))
                url = url + '&'+a+'='+b;
        });

        window.location = url;
    });
```